# Flash element not transparent in Firefox

Tags: html, flash

I put a flash mp3 player element in my HTML page.
This element has a transparent background.

```
<div id="player">
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="100" height="30" id="mp3player" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="mp3player.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
    <param name="play" value="true" />
    <param name="loop" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
    <param name="menu" value="true" />
    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
    <param name="salign" value="" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="mp3player.swf" width="100" height="30">
    <param name="movie" value="mp3player.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
    <param name="play" value="true" />
    <param name="loop" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
    <param name="menu" value="true" />
    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
    <param name="salign" value="" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<!--<![endif]-->
    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
    </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
</object>
</div>
```

Firefox in Windows 7 displays a transparent background while it does not happen with Windows XP.

How can this problem be solved?
Thanks

EDIT

I noticed that my flash element at the start has a transparent background but after mouse-over the background turns black and stays black.
Is possible using jquery to force the flash wmode parameter trasparent on mouse-over and/or
mouse-out?
Thanks

Comment: To confirm, the code provided doesn't have a closing tag for the div with id="player".  Is this the same as in your code?  Also, if you want your background to be transparent, why do you also specify a background colour?

Comment: div player id is closed. If I delete bgcolor the situation does not change.

Comment: You're Firefox and Flash Player Version is up to date? I think, older versions doesn't support this.

Answer (score 0):

While you have:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
```

You still need this as an attribute on the object tag:

```
<object wmode="transparent" ....
```

Comment: I added the parameter, but nothing has changed.
I noticed that my flash element at the start has a transparent background but after mouse-over the background turns black and stays black after.(only in firefox)